# How to validate google payment token in nodejs

Tags: node.js, cryptography, google-pay

I'm trying to validate on backend the payment token that I got from the mobile app which is using google-payments.

The token looks like this:

```
"{\"signature\":\"MEUCIFGFWxmw/6WRXAqEoZAT7TspkckP/Rd5DtfVfa7NHqJ9AiEA1cK5O/hUENf+npc3lKyI1DsKYMA5gNP77Gmhkie/Q00\\u003d\",\"intermediateSigningKey\":{\"signedKey\":\"{\\\"keyValue\\\":\\\"MFkwEwYHKoZIzj0CAQYIKoZIzj0DAQcDQgAEwKVBSYqrKGeBTdL4eXerp+qfUAA3Ie5CINH2aK34iYNpmxn+xDIuD67vthpIRjiKtyGtJvqLHs6MPp3kkru8vg\\\\u003d\\\\u003d\\\",\\\"keyExpiration\\\":\\\"1598399127387\\\"}\",\"signatures\":[\"MEUCIQC0n7zyHhvD8sUJhRa+HOeV6hRl1XscT7wt1G685PxyTAIgTVeq4rR1MFseYZcYJ4nKeNz4BGC9m+ax8i434rCoV6w\\u003d\"]},\"protocolVersion\":\"ECv2\",\"signedMessage\":\"{\\\"encryptedMessage\\\":\\\"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\\\\u003d\\\",\\\"ephemeralPublicKey\\\":\\\"BIi24MIm0uqQ3JoaHQ9mY0tk7z+VV2Uue9zCmxrH+gj/DUwvTRFn0D9g860j7JzsdSTPXKr23CFsKRKvOAypNoU\\\\u003d\\\",\\\"tag\\\":\\\"h41QJdk8uByJnwtKPgZiFQzT4evU4pPDUtpi96tMthk\\\\u003d\\\"}\"}"
```

There are quite extensive docs about the procedure I should implement on backend to validate that the payload is valid and to decode `encryptedMessage` which allegedly contains details of the purchase.

These can be found here: https://developers.google.com/pay/api/android/guides/resources/payment-data-cryptography#using-tink

To my surprise, Google Pay only provides code example of how to accomplish this in Java (using tink libray).
I would really like to not have to add Java service to a system, which otherwise doesn't have it in the stack.

Ideally I would like to validate and decode using nodejs. But I can also settle for Python if need be. Surprisingly I cannot google out a solution to this one and I already spent hours trying to figure implement this using `crypto` module.

Does anyone know of a library that can be used or maybe can share code examples?

Comment: Here's some node.js code that performs the signatures verification: https://notificare.com/blog/2022/07/08/Handle-Google-Wallet-callbacks-with-nodejs/ - note that this code is for verifying the data Google is sending in callbacks when a Google Pass is added/removed to/from a Google Wallet, but the logic for verifying a payment token is the same. You just have to change some constants in that code (such as GOOGLE_SENDER_ID, PROTOCOL_VERSION and GOOGLE_PUBLIC_KEY_URL). Actually - you might need some extra steps for verifying a payment token, since it involves decryption too.

Answer (score -3):

You can not validate the payload data, but using nodejs you could validate the payload structure using joi.

```
// https://npmjs.com/package/joi
const joi = require('joi');

const payload = '{"signature":"MEUCIFGFWxmw/6WRXAqEoZAT7TspkckP/Rd5DtfVfa7NHqJ9AiEA1cK5O/hUENf+npc3lKyI1DsKYMA5gNP77Gmhkie/Q00\\u003d","intermediateSigningKey":{"signedKey":"{\\"keyValue\\":\\"MFkwEwYHKoZIzj0CAQYIKoZIzj0DAQcDQgAEwKVBSYqrKGeBTdL4eXerp+qfUAA3Ie5CINH2aK34iYNpmxn+xDIuD67vthpIRjiKtyGtJvqLHs6MPp3kkru8vg\\\\u003d\\\\u003d\\",\\"keyExpiration\\":\\"1598399127387\\"}","signatures":["MEUCIQC0n7zyHhvD8sUJhRa+HOeV6hRl1XscT7wt1G685PxyTAIgTVeq4rR1MFseYZcYJ4nKeNz4BGC9m+ax8i434rCoV6w\\u003d"]},"protocolVersion":"ECv2","signedMessage":"{\\"encryptedMessage\\":\\"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\\\\u003d\\",\\"ephemeralPublicKey\\":\\"BIi24MIm0uqQ3JoaHQ9mY0tk7z+VV2Uue9zCmxrH+gj/DUwvTRFn0D9g860j7JzsdSTPXKr23CFsKRKvOAypNoU\\\\u003d\\",\\"tag\\":\\"h41QJdk8uByJnwtKPgZiFQzT4evU4pPDUtpi96tMthk\\\\u003d\\"}"}';

const parsedPayload = JSON.parse(payload);
const payloadSchema = joi.object(
  {
    signature: joi.number().string().required("'signature' is missing from the payload"),
    intermediateSigningKey: joi.object().required("'intermediateSigningKey' is a required param and it must be an object."),
    protocolVersion: joi.string().trim().required("'protocolVersion' is a required param."),
    signedMessage: joi.string().trim().required("'signedMessage' is a required param."),
  },
);

const payloadValidationResult = payloadSchema.validate(paymentData);

if (payloadValidationResult.error) {
  console.log(payloadValidationResult.error.details[0]);
}
```

Comment: I didn't downvote, but your "You can not validate the payload data" statement is definitely incorrect. The data contains signatures. If you have a public key + a signature, you can verify the corresponding data. In this question there are two pieces of data to verify - "signedKey", which you use Google's root signing public keys to verify (with the corresponding "signatures"), and "signedMessage", which you use "signedKey"->"keyValue" to verify (with the corresponding "signature").

Comment: @Eran We do not have access to the private key to verify the data. This is done internally by Google. They explained to me it is not possible for us to validate the data, only when we send it to their API. It would be nice to see you tell them that you are right and they are wrong about their own product. Almost 3 years have been passed and not one single person came up with a better solution to this.

Comment: You don't need a private key to verify a signature. You need a public key. And Google explain how to verify the signature here - https://developers.google.com/pay/api/android/guides/resources/payment-data-cryptography#signature-verification